# How to retrieve data from fields inside the fancybox in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

**Background**

So I am building a dashboard. At some point the user presses an 'add widget' button. A fancybox loads the target div inside a fancybox. The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#various1").fancybox({
                    'titlePosition': 'inside',
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'closeBtn': 'true'

                });
        });
    </script>

<!-- Add Widget Button-->
    <div class="cell_title_buttonAddWidget" style="right: 90px;">
        <a id="various1" href="#AddWidget">Add New Widget</a>
    </div>
```

The fancybox contains some textfields and dropdownlists. These dropdownlists are populated by database data. The user makes a selection (e.g. which type of chart he wants to see within the widget). Eventually the user selected all his choices and entered text in the textfields (e.g. Widget Title). User presses "save" button. The code for this looks like this (For the sake of simplicity, I've added only one field for the widget title):

```
<div style="display: none">
        <div id="AddWidget" style="width:800px">
             <div class="cell" style="margin: 0;">
                    <div class="cell_title">Add Widget</div>
                    <table style="margin: 10px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td class="form_label">Widget Title:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="AddWidgetTitle" runat="server" style="width: 250px;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="form_label"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="saveWidget" runat="server" type="button" value="Save" OnServerClick="saveWidget_Click">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**What I want to accomplish for now**

Upon pressing the save button, I want the saveWidget_Click function to be fired, which it does. Then I want to put the value of AddWidgetTitle in a string (later into a database), by reading AddWidgetTitle.value.

**The problem**

Upon pressing the input button, I fire the saveWidget_Click function in my code-behind. However, before doing so, the page_load function is executed. At this point all the textfields and dropdownlist selected items are EMPTY. The textfields read "". I want to save the data within saveWidget_Click function by starting an INSERT query line into my database, but the data is empty.

Maybe I am approaching the 'pop up window with data inside of it' the wrong way. But I am hoping I am just missing something and the thing I want is possible using fancybox.

**In conclusion**

I can populate the textfields and dropdownlists within my fancybox with database data. However, I can't save the edited textfields and selected dropdownlist items within my database, because upon pressing a save button, the page reloads and all the entered data is gone.

Comment: page_load method put inside if(!Page.IsPostBack)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at. Could you explain some more? Thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: on saveWidget_Click what exactly you want